# Fetching from Firebase realtime database takes several seconds [revised]

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase API to fetch data using the Realtime database. Here's a query

```
self.ref.child("books").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    //if the reference have some values
    if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
        //iterating through all the values
        for bookSnapshot in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            if let book = Book(snapshot: bookSnapshot) {
```

On LTE, this query takes 12seconds to load. What would you recommend to speed up database fetching of data?

Here's the structure for books db -

There are multiple nodes like 10-happier.

```
{
"10-happier" : {
  "amazonBuyUrl" : "https://amzn.to/2nuHTHR",
  "audioUrl" : {
    "chapter1" : "https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-2.mp3"
  },
  "author" : "Dan Harris",
  "authorDesc" : "test test",
  "body" : "test test",
  "categories" : [ "Self Development", "Psychology", "Biography & Memoir" ],
  "completed" : {
    "10219993430288225" : 1581846137041,
    "1556272301132307" : 1581916289207,
    "3017569394928984" : 1586155390963,
    "3263627003652258" : 1582049236951,
    "A-3Yk9o0FtfHWlZj515mt3zHxtYeQ2" : 1582128686621,
    "A-7oXx7p9b9jgdfbKwsehbDIBXhGC3" : 1581566535161,
    "A-Ho0APgwxoHURm8O92evZr6G9tkt2" : 1581904896082,
    "A-HtKtSqVZgFMBM1yw4gHm3e2hLUg1" : 1584884159090,
    "A-qxlGjJTfchSECP5YsxJM0wSuSIw1" : 1581792731008,
    "G-105788332369376743421" : 1581818412363,
    "G-113771252263706881621" : 1581738757995
  },
  "courses" : "mindfulness-101",
  "desc" : "test test",
  "free" : false,
  "id" : "10-happier",
  "image" : "https://test.com",
  "lists" : {
    "10101867942050954" : [ "test Test" ]
  },
  "mediaUrl" : "https://test.com/image",
  "publishDate" : 1589475061979,
  "readCount" : 685,
  "starCount" : 59,
  "stars" : {
    "10101867942050954" : true,
    "10157136524486298" : true,
    "10157477945123673" : true,
    "10157499260876070" : true,
    "1017037695358370" : true,
    "10222308106395933" : true,
    "154186932609338" : true,
    "1556272301132307" : true,
    "2661378620608937" : true,
    "2815111171929439" : true,
    "3038320762848045" : true,
    "A-0ypREkE8fRUtnqxOlxQgGWFrdsp1" : true,
    "A-1XY2T9NjZPSTnpIdwKFFWfWJLx33" : true,
    "A-2rUW7UcYCcT0uZhdxUiO51gPw8N2" : true,
    "A-2v24CZFRW8budbcPWaXB528pXhE2" : true,
    "A-3phIjft84KRjnx3nG8gvvuuExHa2" : true,
    "A-9TaI4W9sHEhFdiuBtRwLRJPaPv72" : true,
    "A-ABOJnyIloSVSfAx06Sp5qX9WKzq1" : true,
    "A-AR3XlMB3QkbVQRvREMhzOjdJKhd2" : true,
    "A-EF1gKttAbYfJEiGx0UjO5KiHbPo2" : true,
    "A-Frq5L8B0A5dbsLNMkMcUv1DKw7F2" : true,
    "A-N4rVyl26YeYCYKtZCYQVbBL6dMh2" : true,
    "A-NWvtTI4spCeCrxmoz8fpEZp68T43" : true,
    "A-NkAFmiH3ohSOIKUKDKLWzlAbc533" : true,
    "A-NvDpA1BZSSSBrpXjjvydM8iqFBQ2" : true,
    "A-PCrfGOW5cqRVoAgA4DqyCqBb1F22" : true,
    "A-QVfzwTST5VOMUxR4oZEHk7rNU9J3" : true,
    "A-RIPsjzsChjXM3Xi7XG4N45R7YIv1" : true,
    "A-W8PlMnlmBsTgUfgqLUseSNJmE0W2" : true,
    "A-Wj3KVZtFmtZRrS1439mUkWfVtIm1" : true,
    "A-YUjrDlXJ1fabthCvgY1Khu5ogVR2" : true,
    "A-YhDT27Ri5Reb12EFHlh00j6dZy53" : true,
    "A-cJNzJZplLZVftha8MGQvbTj4DnE2" : true,
    "A-h49UQNkPDuSM135br3eE2Q8LzCW2" : true,
    "A-lIxOylTfoFWJHTtbE4moylPz04B2" : true,
    "A-rYRWKnQMTMgwQihrr2GPjTOpfEB3" : true,
    "A-u3fWRq2ZqyVQhjjBD1Xkhpc9SUs1" : true,
    "A-u4vyWb96rsdQNcgnwYkOZ46aTeY2" : true,
    "A-ugChjAs0vTRae7Bby6AQzXVPbC83" : true,
    "A-zd22udZZfjfs5hF1SAeAQmEpenl1" : true,
    "A-zi1RWeLxrmXQmPbzqN6gERUyJps2" : true
  },
  "subtitle" : "How I Tamed the Voice in My Head, Reduced Stress Without Losing My Edge, and Found Self-Help That Actually Works--A True Story",
  "tags" : [ "nyt" ],
  "title" : "10% Happier",
  "uploadDate" : 1589475061979,
  "video" : "https://test.com/video"
    }
}
```

The database is 3.4MB in size. There are over 250 nodes.

Comment: You're got something wrong somewhere. If that's a typical node in your Firebase, its roughly 3.1k worth of data. If you have 250 nodes, that's a whopping .79 Mb (less than 1Mb). There is protocol and encryption overhead (approx 3.5k) for firebase so call it .8Mb. That is not equal to 3.4Mb. On LTE, that should download in it's entirety in about 1.5s or less. In other words, it's a tiny amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned the first time you asked this question, you will need to reduce the amount of data in the query. If you don't need all this data at once, split it up into different nodes, and query each node separately as needed.

But I will say that your so-called LTE connection seems quite slow with the metrics you're showing here. The query itself is not really providing any overhead, since you are simply asking for the entire contents of a single node.